# app.yaml file for a python program

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How do I write an `app.yaml` file for a particular Python app I'm trying to put on Google App Engine?

Here is the simple python code I'm trying to work on:

```
import webapp2
form="""
<form action="http://www.google.com/search">
<input name="q">
<input type="submit">
</form>
"""
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(form)

app=webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/',MainPage)],
                              debug=True)
```

Now whenever I'm trying to run it on Google App Engine, it simply doesn't work. Shows nothing  on localhost and shows server error while deploying it.

Here is the `app.yaml` code:

```
application: saaps-2012
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
script: program.py
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the following lines in the end of your file `program.py`:

```
def main():
    app.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Your file should then look like something like this:

```
import webapp2
form="""
<form action="http://www.google.com/search">
<input name="q">
<input type="submit">
</form>
"""
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(form)

app=webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/',MainPage)],
                              debug=True)

def main():
    app.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Have a try and let me know about your results.

Comment: Thanks!Now it did work on Localhost.
But still showing that error on appspot.com after deploying the app out there. 

Here is the exact error message:
**Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.**

Comment: Check the Logs tab in the Admin Console (see sidebar navigation).